# How do I get notified to every activity in my repository?

Tags: github

So, I'm using just normal GitHub. The Repository is private and I have about 6 Contributors. I have many branches in the repo from different contributors, and I want to get notified for every update (Anything. Starting from the push and pull requests to issues, and more) done in my repository. How can I do that?

I read about this before, someone said you can set up a Webhook. But, I still didn't understand it. I want to know in simple terms if possible.

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/webhooks/using-webhooks/creating-webhooks this outlines how to create github webhooks -- it even has an option for "Send me everything" :)